# Why is mtr more reliable than traceroute, on my ISP?

Tags: ipv6, traceroute

My `traceroute6` results are truncated, while the results from `mtr` span the whole path.  Why would this happen?

mtr uses ICMP ECHO by default<del>, just like traceroute</del>.  Running traceroute under `sudo` does not change the result.  Nor does `-M tcp` or `-M udp` or `-M icmp`.

(Note I am deliberately testing the "production version of IP".  The legacy "experimental version" works as expected :-).

### mtr

```
$ time mtr -n --report -c 1 google.co.uk
Start: Thu Aug 11 11:29:08 2016
HOST: localhost.localdomain       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:924d:4af  0.0%     1    5.7   5.7   5.7   5.7   0.0
  2.|-- ???                       100.0     1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  3.|-- ???                       100.0     1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  4.|-- ???                       100.0     1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  5.|-- 2a00:2380:3013:9000::8     0.0%     1   23.1  23.1  23.1  23.1   0.0
  6.|-- 2a00:2380:13::23           0.0%     1   23.2  23.2  23.2  23.2   0.0
  7.|-- 2a00:2380:2001:5000::d     0.0%     1   19.2  19.2  19.2  19.2   0.0
  8.|-- 2001:4860:0:1::1049        0.0%     1   13.0  13.0  13.0  13.0   0.0
  9.|-- 2001:4860:0:1::8f          0.0%     1   19.6  19.6  19.6  19.6   0.0
 10.|-- 2a00:1450:4009:809::2003   0.0%     1   24.0  24.0  24.0  24.0   0.0

real    0m6.229s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.011s
```

### traceroute6

```
$ time traceroute -6 -n google.co.uk
traceroute to google.co.uk (2a00:1450:4009:809::2003), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:924d:4aff:fe06:1c9  3.351 ms  3.324 ms  5.569 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  2a00:2302::1103:100:37  20.128 ms !X  20.118 ms !X  20.120 ms !X

real    0m0.221s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.006s
```

### tracepath6

> tracepath is similar to traceroute, only does not require superuser privileges and has no fancy options.
>
> It uses UDP  port  port or some random port.
>
> tracepath6 is [a] good replacement for traceroute6 and [a] classic example of application  of  Linux error queues.

```
$ time tracepath6 -n google.co.uk
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.035ms pmtu 1488
 1:  fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:924d:4aff:fe06:1c9                   4.101ms 
 1:  fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:924d:4aff:fe06:1c9                   3.161ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  2a00:2302::1103:100:36                               17.379ms asymm  5 
 4:  2a00:2302::1103:100:37                               17.222ms !A
     Resume: pmtu 1488 

real    0m5.068s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Results vary slightly between runs: sometimes hop 3 is not shown.  The addresses of hop 3 or 4 also happen to change (regardless of the tool used); it looks like two different paths are used.

When `mtr` is run interactively, it's eventually able to find hop 3 (though not hop 4).  That hop shows 80-90% loss.  (As noted on the NANOG list, expert networking knowledge is required to fully understand the output of tools like mtr :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traceroute manpage says `!X` indicates one of the ICMP *error* responses (other than the desired "TTL exceeded").  `traceroute` gives up when it sees one.  It looks like `mtr` is more robust.

It's a weird case.  I can't think why you'd replace a "TTL exceeded" response with "administratively prohibited", when packets with a large enough TTL are simply let through.  Thanks to `mtr` for tolerating this weirdness :).

> After the trip time, some additional annotation can be printed: !H, !N,
>          or !P  (host,  network  or  protocol  unreachable),  !S  (source  route
>          failed),  !F (fragmentation needed), !X (communication administratively
>          prohibited), !V (host precedence violation), !C (precedence  cutoff  in
>          effect),  or  !  (ICMP unreachable code ).  If almost all the
>          probes result in some kind of unreachable, traceroute will give up  and
>          exit.

Comment: !X is a common response when the packets have been blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Yah.  The reason it's weird is the firewall's _only_ quibble is expired TTL.  Otherwise, I'm being allowed to send these packets.  If they have a higher TTL they're not blocked by the firewall.  Packets with expired TTL generate the `!X`, which identifies the firewall address just as well as the expected "TTL exceeded".  I can imagine a firewall config that does this but not why you would ever implement it!  I wonder if it is caused by the endpoint of a tunnel (which transits over an ipv4 net).

Comment: I was referring not to _your_ firewall, but a firewall elsewhere on the Internet. The firewalls on Red Hat based systems _default_ to returning administratively prohibited for denied traffic.

Comment: I know it's not my firewall, I'm not sure where I was unclear about this :). I mean my _ISP_ is allowing me to send these UDP packets to google.com.  My ISP is _not_ blocking me from sending the UDP packets to google.com, but that's how traceroute6 (understandably) interprets the response, and why it decides there's no point continuing the trace beyond the weird firewall.  What my ISP is apparently doing is prohibiting me from sending UDP packets to google.com _if the TTL expires at a specific hop_. I mean what's the threat, does hop 4 have a buggy IP stack that's allergic to the number zero?

Comment: Never said I was surprised that a firewall uses "communication administratively prohibited" to indicate blocked traffic. Those words all make sense (& I know the behaviour is extant and common).

Comment: I can't work out what you're trying to contribute.  It sounds like "yeah I know this is something that happens", while ignoring the question at hand about the difference between mtr and traceroute.